# Searching for a large number in ElasticSearch returning no results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have numeric fields mapped as "long" in my ES index. When I search for a number in a field, it returns the correct results if the number is small (<8 digits or so), but when I search for a larger number (e.g. 95799217691324420) I get no results even though there is definitely an entry with that value. The large number is still below the "long" limit of 2 ** 63 so I don't know where the issue lies.

I am querying ES directly from a Python app. I have also tried querying with Kibana and get the same results.

This is what the relevant part of my Kibana query looks like:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "guild_id": 543936797294460900
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
}
```

This is what part of my Python app's query looks like:

```
{
    'bool': {
        'filter': [
            {'match_phrase': 
                {'guild_id': int(request.args['group'])}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Both return zero results. My ES version is 7.6.2. There are no other parameters than "long" in my mapping. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: I think this may be related to [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15292). Does it work if you send the number as a string, and let Elastic do the conversion?

Comment: I saw that, but I'm using Python, not JavaScript, which seems to be the problem in the linked issue. I'm sure it would work if it was typed as text, but I need it to be numeric in order to do a range query.